# Mean of every nth element of swift array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array, where I want the mean of every nth element, starting from a specific element (in this case every 4th, starting at 1). What's the fastest way to do this?

My current method is a for loop with a looping switch statement, but I want to know if there's a quicker way.

I wondered if something like this could work:

```
let num_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let mean4th = num_array[Array(stride(from: 1, to: num_array.count, by: 4))].reduce(0, +) / (num_array.count / 4)
```

Hoping to get `mean4th = 3` (i.e. (1 + 5)/2)

This returns the error

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array<UInt8>' with an index of type 'Array<Int>'
```

..which I'm struggling to get around

Comment: Why do you want to make it faster and less readable? You have to launch this code x times per second? It's for an array with thousands of numbers?

Comment: Indeed. I want this to run on a 500k element array, at 60 Hz

Comment: I currently get about 25 Hz with the for loop

Comment: Can you please also provide an expected output for your example ?

Comment: Added, thanks for the pointer

Comment: you can possible use something like this : `num_array.enumerate.filter($0.index % 4 == 0).reduce...` but that's probably equivalent to your loop

Comment: On the topic of speed, you'll need at some point to evaluate every item in the array, so I don't see any solution being faster than O(n)

Comment: By the way... the error you're getting is cause of the subscription access on `num_array`. You probably meant something like `let mean4th = stride(from: 1, to: num_array.count, by: 4).reduce(0, +) / (num_array.count / 4)`

Comment: I wondered if there was a reshape style transform from 1-D to 2-D, that could then be reduced?

Comment: @Alladinian My example num_array is misleading.. my actual data isn't monotonic.. I need to index an unknown array of values, hence the use of stride for the indexing

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you meant by `Hz` in your comments but one way to do it is to generate the indices of all the elements you are going to visit and iterate from there:

```
let num_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let indices = Array(stride(from: 0, to: num_array.count, by: 4))

let mean = Double(indices.reduce(0) { $0 + num_array[$1] }) / Double(indices.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The array cannot use a sequence as its subscript but you could write it differently

```
  let mean4th = stride(from: 0, to: num_array.count-1, by: 4).reduce(0) {$0 + num_array[$1] } / (num_array.count / 4)
```

The idea of using indices (Code Different) is on the right track, but on very large arrays, building the temporary indices array is adding to the processing time ( 5 times longer on a 500K element array )

The times I get on a MacBook Pro for 500K (in the playground) is 0.41 ms which is well below the 16.7 ms needed for 60Hz. You probably are doing more that just this average computation though so the faster the better.